# `fresh` name: use match result if variable, do something else if it's a constant

Tags: coq, ltac

In a solver tactic, I'm trying to generate reasonably readable names for the generated hypotheses (so things are at least somewhat readable in cases where the automation fails).  `fresh` is happy with identifiers or strings, but doesn't like constants. So in the big match I have repeated cases like:

```
   match goal with
   | |- context [ if (?a + ?b <? ?a) then _ else _ ] =>
     let W := fresh "W" a b in solve_overflow_test W a b
(* | … *)
   end
```

which work fine if I get a situation like `n + m <? n` (generating `Wnm` as the name), but fail if I run into a `n + 1 <? n`, where `fresh` complains about the `1` being neither an identifier nor a string.

I can manually expand a test and substitute placeholders inline, as in

```
   match goal with
   | |- context [ if (?a + ?b <? ?a) then _ else _ ] =>
     tryif is_var a
       then
         tryif is_var b
         then let W := fresh "W" a b in solve_overflow_test W a b
         else let W := fresh "W" a "_" in solve_overflow_test W a b
       else
         tryif is_var b
         then let W := fresh "W" "_" b in solve_overflow_test W a b
         else let W := fresh "W" "_" "_" in solve_overflow_test W a b
(* | … *)
   end
```

but that's an *exponential* 2^n blowup in tactic size, which *really* isn't worth the slight improvement in readability of the generated proof.

So I'd like to tuck the test & substitution away into a helper tactic. `is_var` and friends aren't value tactics, and [while there's apparently a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45949064/805875)), I couldn't get it to work here.  (I'm not returning values, but… ??? and CPS-ing everything after the `fresh` (if that's even an option) would also be too ugly.)

Is there a way that I missed, or should I rather just give up on including the matched identifiers in the generated names?

Comment: Is the use of [Ltac2](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proof-engine/ltac2.html) a possible choice in your context?

Comment: @ErikMD no idea, never used it before – if it's interoperable with "plain"/"old" `Ltac` (the way LaTeX3 is with its predecessor) then probably, otherwise no.

Comment: OK, so I guess importing `Ltac2` is not the best strategy. However, are you sure you need to write `fresh "W" a b`? for your use case, I'd suggest to just write `fresh "W"`: according to the [doc](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.fresh), each call to the `fresh` tactic always generates a unique identifier…

Comment: @ErikMD The problem is that I can easily get 5+ of these, and if they're called `Wxy, Wxz, …` that's both more readable and also the names are predictable (thus more stable in case of changes) compared to `W1, W2, …` (where the order of generation matters for which one ends up with what number.) But yeah for now I've given up and am just using slightly longer names like `HOverflow` plus generated numbers. (Still, thanks for your suggestions anyway!)